# Filtering data by one column using two criteria in Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a dataset where I'm trying to filter data using one column and two criteria within the column using Teradata SQL.  See sample dataset below:

| CUST_ID | SALES | CLASS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | CLASS1 |
| 1 | 400 | CLASS1 |
| 1 | 600 | NULL |
| 2 | 300 | CLASS2 |
| 2 | 600 | NULL |
| 2 | 900 | CLASS2 |
| 3 | 100 | NULL |
| 3 | 200 | CLASS1 |
| 3 | 300 | CLASS1 |

See desired output below:

| CUST_ID | SALES | CLASS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | CLASS1 |
| 1 | 400 | CLASS1 |
| 1 | 600 | NULL |
| 3 | 100 | NULL |
| 3 | 200 | CLASS1 |
| 3 | 300 | CLASS1 |

I was trying to filter the data using OVER PARTITION in the WHERE clause but it's returning CLASS1 and all the nulls, including CUSTID 2, which I don't want.  I want to filter CLASS1 with nulls by CUSTID.

```
SELECT CUSTID, SALES, CLASS FROM DATASET1
WHERE CLASS IS IN ('CLASS1' OR 'NULL');
```

Is it impossible to filter 1 column using two criteria in teradata SQL?

Comment: `'NULL'` is a literal value, you must use IS NULL to check for NULLs: `WHERE CLASS IN ('CLASS1') OR CLASS IS NULL;`

Comment: And `IN` wants a list, e.g. `WHERE CLASS IN ('CLASS1', 'CLASS2', 'CLASS3')`.

Comment: @dnoeth I created the class column and added the word NULL.  Using the change you suggested I'm still getting back CLASS1 only but I need the nulls returned also.

Comment: @jarlh using your suggestion still returns NULL from CLASS2 which I don't want.  I only want CLASS1 and associated NULL by CUSTID.

Comment: It was a syntax example, not an answer.

Comment: Seems you want the cust_ids with only NULLs or CLASS1 in all rows? `select * from dataset1 qualify max(case when class in ('class1', 'null') then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by cust_id) = 0`, the max returns 1 when there's any other value in the rows of a customer.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The qualify i've only just discovered for SQL.